# How to use System.IO.FileSystem in Roslyn based script?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

Most probably I am not seeing woods for the tree but here it is:

How to use *System.IO.FileSystem* in scripts?

I have a project based on 4.6.1 framework that has *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis. Scripting* package installed with NuGet. After that, I have a number of references added where *System.IO.FileSystem* is among them. I cannot add it with *using* keyword in project source file. Also, when found in script code, I receive compilation error:

*The type or namespace 'FileSystem' does not exists in the namespace 'System.IO'*

What am I missing here? I see that there is *System.IO.FileSystem.dll* in target folder. I know how to load DLL dynamically (*Assembly.LoadFile*) but I do not see that as proper way.

Edited:

Here is code sample that is used for this:

```
        string ScriptText = text_Result.Text;

        try
        {
            var Script = CSharpScript.Create<string>(ScriptText, options: ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("System.IO.FileSystem"));
            //Script.Compile();
            string Result = Script.RunAsync(null, null).Result.ReturnValue;
            text_Result.Text += Environment.NewLine + Result + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            text_Result.Text += Environment.NewLine + MyError.Message + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

The error is the same:

```
(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to that assembly in your Roslyn scripting session, not your host project.

Specifically, use `ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(...)`.

Comment: I edited question with code that is used as per your suggestion. Still the same error.

Comment: It probably can't resolve the reference.  Check for diagnostics from `Compile()`, and try passing an `Assembly`.

Comment: After examinig return value of Compile() I am getting the same error as attached. However, Compile() does not generate run-time error like RunAsync.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear be a type or namespace named "System.IO.FileSystem" in the dll named "System.IO.FileSystem.dll".

In fact there is nothing in that DLL except type forwarders to types that used to be in that DLL but are now in mscorlib, and none of them are in the namespace System.IO.FileSystem or are a class named FileSystem.  They are all in the namespace System.IO.

for example, you can create the type System.IO.FileSystemWatcher in a script like this:

```
var code = "return new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();";
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(FileSystemWatcher).Assembly.Location);
var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, options);
var watcher = script.RunAsync().Result.ReturnValue;
```

System.IO.FileSystemWatcher is actually found in System.DLL

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is part of System.IO namespace and is accessible after adding _using System.IO_. If I understand correctly, System.IO.FileSystem is part of Net.Core but project reference and appropriate dll are added with addition of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting package via NuGet. I want to understand if I can use, in my scripts, that and other namespaces added with scripting. Regardless of the fact that host project is 4.6.1 based.

Comment: The scripting API is going to run your scripts in the same process as your app, so you'll want to be using references to libraries that can run on the platform (desktop/core/etc) that your app is using.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I should include in my scripts only assemblies that are available under appropriate version (4.6.1 currently). On the other hand, references that are added after _Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting_ inclusion are needed for Roslyn to work.